# How to check if time is similar every 8 rows after floor_date function (and correct it if needed)

Tags: r

I have a dataset where new data are recorded at a fixed interval (3-4 minutes). Each 8 records (rows) correspond to a same set of data (CC_01->04 and DC01->04) that I want to stamp to the previous half-hour.

For this I use the floor date function of lubridate that works perfectly:

```
lubridate::floor_date(data$Date_IV, "30 minutes")
```

However, sometimes the eighth record starts after the begining of the next half-hour and so the floor_date function stamps it with this new half-hour. But I would like it to be stamped with the previous one (as part of the subset).

Therefore I'm looking for a way to check when this eighth value differs from the previous 7, and correct it if needed.

An exemple :

```
  Label             Date_IV Obs.  Exp_Flux          Floor_date
1  CC_01 2021-07-08 12:38:00    1 -0.290000 2021-07-08 12:30:00
2  DC_01 2021-07-08 12:42:00    2  3.830000 2021-07-08 12:30:00
3  CC_02 2021-07-08 12:45:00    3 -0.527937 2021-07-08 12:30:00
4  DC_02 2021-07-08 12:49:00    4  2.260000 2021-07-08 12:30:00
5  CC_03 2021-07-08 12:52:00    5 -0.743471 2021-07-08 12:30:00
6  DC_03 2021-07-08 12:55:00    6  2.230000 2021-07-08 12:30:00
7  CC_04 2021-07-08 12:59:00    7 -1.510000 2021-07-08 12:30:00
8  DC_04 2021-07-08 13:02:00    8  1.820000 2021-07-08 13:00:00
9  CC_01 2021-07-08 13:05:00    9 -0.190000 2021-07-08 13:00:00
10 DC_01 2021-07-08 13:08:00   10  3.750000 2021-07-08 13:00:00
11 CC_02 2021-07-08 13:11:00   11 -0.423572 2021-07-08 13:00:00
12 DC_02 2021-07-08 13:14:00   12  2.230000 2021-07-08 13:00:00
13 CC_03 2021-07-08 13:18:00   13 -0.635882 2021-07-08 13:00:00
14 DC_03 2021-07-08 13:22:00   14  2.670000 2021-07-08 13:00:00
15 CC_04 2021-07-08 13:25:00   15 -1.440000 2021-07-08 13:00:00
16 DC_04 2021-07-08 13:29:00   16  1.860000 2021-07-08 13:00:00
```

In my example, the first 8 lines should be stamped to to 12:30:00. The function works for the first 7, but the eighth is stamped to 13:00 as the record was done at 13:02.

This situation doesn't appear for the second measurements set (lines 9->16) as the last measurement started before the next half-hour, so the eight are stamped with 13:00, which is correct. Nothing to correct here.

These measurements are repeated many times, so I cannot modify it by hands.

I hope it makes sens.

Thanks in advance for your help,
Adrien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a group of every 8 rows or create a new group every time `CC_01` occurs whichever is most appropriate according to your data and take `floor_date` value of first value in the group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data %>%
  group_by(grp = ceiling(Obs/8)) %>%
  #Or increment the group value at every occurrence of CC_01
  #group_by(grp = cumsum(Label == 'CC_01')) %>%
  mutate(Floor_date = floor_date(first(Date_IV), '30 minutes')) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak Shah, your solution perfectly worked!